# Google analytics average visit duration fall

Tags: google-analytics

In recent 2 days, my website's average visits duration fell from about 1:30 to 50sec in Audience>Overview window and fell from 2:00 to 1:30 in Content>Overview window. The visits duration parameters has a steady value for a long time.
The website (www.rapidtables.com) seems to function well.
Hosting server activity history graph seems normal.
All other analytics parameters (visits and pages/visit) seem normal.
Why visit duration is different in Audience>Overview and Content>Overview windows?
What could have caused the sudden drop in the duration parameter? (analytics bug / old urchin.js usage ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have historical data to compare to? If so, is this the first year it has happened, or do you see a dip about this time every year?  If you have absolutely verified that nothing went wrong with your tracking code or your website in general, then it boils down to speculation. You just have to research the industry your site caters to and look for reasons that might have caused it.  Maybe some new competitor opened shop? Maybe whatever product or service you offer is "seasonal"?

Comment: This is the first time it happens. I looked with the recent 2 years history. The drop accured in many unrelated pages.

Comment: Update: the visit duration for 31/1 is back to normal - probelm still happens with recent 2 days (including today's) - seems like analytics bug...